# How to keep selected entry blank and use CollectionView - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Following on from a previous question I posted, I have a `CollectionView` which contains a filtered list of objects from an `ObservableCollection`.

Problem is, I want my selected item in my combo box of my datagrid to not be populated with an entry from my `CollectionView` until I actually hit the dropdown box and select an item from within it. Everytime the `CollectionView` source becomes populated the first item in that source is selected automatically in the combobox which i don't want. I want to essentially have an empty item that is not associated with the `CollectionView` I am bound to.

The XAML i have is as follows:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bl" MinWidth="80" x:Name="Bled">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.BlModels, Source={x:Reference SaeDataGrid}}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Sme" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Bladel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValuePath="GrId"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Bladel.GrId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=Blanned, Path=MinWidth}" 
                      Style="{StaticResource SamboBox}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.BlModels, Source={x:Reference SaeDataGrid}}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Sme"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Bladel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  Style="{StaticResource SamboBox}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and my collection view

```
private CollectionView blModels;
public CollectionView BlModels
{
    get { return blModels; }
    set
    {
        if (value != blModels)
        {
            blModels = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => BlModels);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out [this blog post](http://graemehill.ca/nullable-combo-boxes-in-wpf/) for a potential solution.

Comment: Not sure if it would. I tried using a <sys:string> and CollectionContainer in the ComboBox but the complaint is about DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath having "No Target" :\